# Добавление абзаца в таблицу Word через Apache POI

Tags: java, apache

Всем привет!
Проблема в следующем: есть текст в котором есть абзацы.
Необходимо этот текст поместить в таблицу(ячейку). Текст получается записать в таблицу, но в строчку без абзацев. Что делать не знаю...помогите пожалуйста.
Использую библиотеку Apache POI

```
String shapkaString = "Акционерное общество"
         +  "\"Российский концерн по производству электрической\n"
         + "и тепловой энергии на атомных станциях\"\n"
         + "(АО \"Концерн Росэнергоатом\")\n"
         + "Филиал АО \"Концерн Росэнергоатом\"\n"
         + "\"РОСТОВСКАЯ АТОМНАЯ СТАНЦИЯ\"\n"
         + "(Ростовская АЭС, Волгодонск-28)\n"
         + "Отдел дефектоскопии металлов и технического контроля";
        XWPFTable shapka = document.createTable();
        XWPFTableRow nameCo = shapka.createRow();
        nameCo.getCell(0).setText(shapkaString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы применились символы "\n"  - на стиль ячейки используйте функцию setWrapText

```
CellStyle wrapStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
wrapStyle.setWrapText(true);
cell.setCellStyle(wrapStyle);
```